# iOS App Store keeps asking for password for free items

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, apple-id, touch-id

Has the option to just download free apps from the App Store without password been removed?

I tried signing in through the Settings app, the App Store no longer lets me use Touch ID for free items.

How do I make iOS App Store either not ask for password or allow Touch ID I already have the option set in Settings app.

I am running iOS 11.2.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It’s not removed, but it can get stuck. I would disable this feature and then reboot if you think it’s already enabled. Also, free apps are basically the same as paid - you go through all the same hoops to “buy” save an optional second confirmation for payments.

To allow downloading from the App Store without having to enter your password every time for free apps follow these steps:

- Go to Settings
- Scroll down and click Itunes and App Stores
- Click Password Settings
- Toggle off "Require Password" under Free Downloads.

You will now be able download apps without having to enter your password.

**UPDATE**

I since found the issue was localized to a bad home WiFi/router which blocked access to Apple servers. This can be verified by:

- signing out of App Store in settings
- trying to sign back in
- getting an error message
- disconnecting from WiFi, using cellular
- signing back in
- getting the “verify payment alert”
- entering credit card Security code or selecting “none” payment type
- this enables Touch ID for purchases

Comment: I also faced this problem on ios 12, i couldn't download free app with Touch ID. This helped me: sign out of App Store in settings (settings-app store-your icloud account-log out), login again, downloading free apps with Touch ID works.

Comment: @littleguga Thanks! I had the same issue and your steps solved it. Can't believe how bad the UI is.

Comment: There is not setting --> itunes (in 14.1).